# Запись составного высказывания в коде

Tags: c#, .net

Даны высказывания:

- Высказывание A: Конь - животное
- Высказывание B: Ночью светит солнце
- Высказывание С: 5 больше 999
- Высказывание D: (100 - 5) равно 95

Записать на языке `C#` следующие логические выражения(составные высказывания):

```
logicalExpressionX1 = A И НЕ(B)
logicalExpressionX2 = C ИЛИ D
logicalExpressionX3 = (A И НЕ(B)) ИЛИ B
logicalExpressionX4 = logicalExpressionX1 И С
logicalExpressionX5 = logicalExpressionX1 ИЛИ logicalExpressionX4
```

Вывести значение каждого логического выражения в консоль.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вам нужно прочитать про логические операторы и с помощью них просто создать строку. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: Я знаю операторы. Не понял про созданеи строки.
Я создал стринговые переменные с высказываниями, а теперь не знаю как записать составные высказывания, пишу if(a && !b) получается ошибка, и так со всеми.

Comment: Значит, стоит еще прочитать про условные конструкции. Строки не умеют приводиться к `bool`.

Comment: @And, это я тоже знаю, у меня проблема конкретно в этой задаче.

Comment: Ну дело все в том, что для цифровых комбинаций, это еще куда не шло, сделать можно и не составит труда, а вот для строковых, не имея никакой последовательности и так сказать реализации, у вас сделать это не выйдет. Как вам программа сможет понять, что `Конь - животное`, в чем заключается истинность, почему это не ложь? Почему нельзя подумать, что это `Млекопитающее`? Как вам программа должна понять, что это животное? Совершенно верно никак! Тут только переопределять или делать свою какую-то  `Дизъюнкцию` и `Конъюнкцию`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать вот такую конструкцию, с помощью которой можно решить вашу задачу.

```
public class StatementTools
    {
        public static string OperatorOR(string text1, string text2)
        {
            return text1 + " или " + text2;
        }
        public static string OperatorAnd (string text1, string text2)
        {
            return text1 + " и " + text2;
        }
        public static string OperatorNot(string text)
        {
            return "не " + text; 
        }
    }
    static void Foo()
    {
        string a = "Конь - животное";
        string b = "Ночью светит солнце";
        string logicalExpressionX1 = StatementTools.OperatorAnd(a, StatementTools.OperatorNot(b));
        Console.WriteLine(logicalExpressionX1);
    }
```

Comment: по-моему это слишком замудренный код. Разве не надо просто записать составные высказывания под c# и результат вывести в консоль?

Comment: Ну как минимум вы не можете перегрузить логический оператор "&&" или "||",поэтому реализовать свои операторы , это нормально для этой задачи.

Comment: @Student а как компилятор должен решать какие выражения истинные, а какие ложные если они записаны обычной строкой?

Comment: есть же условие

Comment: Как компилятор должен понять что ваша строка это true или false? У него нет ИИ что бы прочитать содержание и понять, что Солнце ночью не светит.